# Spring JPA @OneToMany not persisting the children

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Before I start I checked few posts and none of them resolved my problem.

Please can someone guide me here. I wanted to establish a Plant(1) to Inventories(n) Relationship.

I created couple of models, one for Plant as below where I mention the OneToMany relationship

```
@Entity
public class Plant implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long plantID;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "plant", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Inventory> listInventory = new ArrayList<>();
getter and setter....
```

And another one for Inventory where I mention ManyToOne relationship

```
@Entity
public class Inventory implements Serializable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long inventoryId;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "plantID", nullable = false)
private Plant plant;
```

When I try to persist the data like below, it saves the plant (parent) but not its children's.

As part of persisting the data, I did something like below

```
public Plant addPlant(String plantName, List<Inventory> listMaterial, PlantRepository plantRepository, InventoryRepository inventoryRepository) {
    Plant plant = new Plant();
    List<Inventory> listInventory = new ArrayList<>();
    plant.setPlantName(plantName);

    for (Inventory inventory : listMaterial) {
        inventory.setPlant(plant);
        listInventory.add(inventory);
    }
    plant.setListInventory(listInventory);
    return plantRepository.save(plant);
}
```

After reading few posts I found that I should set the association of plant with the inventory before persisting. So I did added the code for the same but it went on infinite or just my STS hanged.

I am sure I am doing something wrong but not sure where. Please can someone guide me through.

My expectation is that Inventory will be a reference table where I will have list of inventories. When I add a new plant, I will map few of the inventories to this plant. Similarly this will happen for many plants and many inventories.

As part of persistence, I will have to save plant and its inventories. I should also be able to pass the plant ID and retrieve the corresponding Inventories.

**UPDATE 1:** 
Also I am not sure if the relation I am using is fair enough for this scenario. As my inventory is a reference table and at the same time, when a plant is mapped to multiple inventories, each inventory can be modified before persisting.

I tried @ManyToMany and it stores the relation in a 3rd table with a unique reference to both the tables but I wont be able to get the details of each inventory record. 
With @ManyToMany, when I fetch it bring the values from the reference table and not the modified one which was persisted with the parent(plant) Please any advise

**UPDATE 2**

I tried with the same models but I changed the way I persist the data as below.

```
public Plant addPlant(String plantName, List<Inventory> listMaterial, PlantRepository plantRepository, InventoryRepository inventoryRepository) {
Plant plant = new Plant();
List<Inventory> listInventory = new ArrayList<>();
plant.setPlantName(plantName);

for (Inventory inventory : listMaterial) {
    plant.addInventoryToPlant(inventory);
}

return plantRepository.save(plant);
```

}

Here is the add method in my plant model

```
public void addInventoryToPlant(Inventory inventory) {
    listInventory.add(inventory);
    inventory.setPlant(this);
}
```

It is just overwriting the inventory table with different plant IDs but not creating a reference table or join table to maintain all the possible mappings. If I try to add a plant with 2 inventories, it maps them first to the Inventory table. If I add another plant then this is getting overwritten. I was in an assumption that it will create a third table to maintain this entity

Comment: can you show us the full transactional method where u populate that data?

Comment: also instead of inventory.add(plant).. you probably meant inventory.setPlant(plant)?

Comment: I have done this in the past.. I hope my relationship is correct in the model and the issue could be the way I persist the data.. Something like I persist the child and then persist the parent?

Comment: Hibernate can't know who is right if your `OneToMany` and `ManyToOne` values are conflicting (contradictory data). To avoid this, Hibernate considers the `@ManyToOne` value as the master and the `@OneToMany` as the slave in the context. When both are present, the master is used.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. Thanks for your response. In my case should I persist the parent and child, kind of one after the other?

Comment: Also I am not sure if the relation I am using is fair enough for this scenario. As my inventory is a reference table and at the same time, when a plant is mapped to multiple inventories, each inventory can be modified before persisting. 

I tried manytomany and it stores the relation in a 3rd table with a unique reference to both the tables but I wont be able to get the details of each inventory record.

With manytomany, when I fetch it bring the values from the reference table and not the modified one which was persisted with the parent(plant)

Please any advise

Comment: Two questions.. Is that list - List<Inventory> listMaterial .. already present in the database and we are just updating the plant? And is the addPlant marked as Transactional? or is part of another transaction?

Comment: @MaciejKowalski Yes it is a list which is displayed from the database. Each plant can be mapped to n number of Inventories, it will also allow the user to modify the data of each inventory. So I have to capture the modified inventory, persist the plant and map the modified inventories to this plant

No I didnt mark it as Transactional

Comment: "It is just overwriting the inventory table with different plant IDs but not creating a reference table or join table to maintain all the possible mappings." - why should it? A foreign key referencing the 'one' table in the 'many' table is enough to represent a one-to-many association. If you want a joining table instead, use `@JoinTable` instead of `@JoinColumn`. Be advised that a `UNIQUE` constraint on the `PLANT_ID` column will be created in the join table to ensure the relationship is indeed one-to-many

Comment: @crizzis Thanks for your response. Plant and Inventory is a reference table. Even if I have the 3rd table, I guess It will again refer the same Inventory table. In my case, where can I store the inventory details of each plant as my inventory table will be a reference table and cant be modified. Please guide me

Comment: I don't quite understand. What do you mean by 'reference table'? As I said, if you use `@JoinTable`, no additional column will be created in the `INVENTORY` table. Is an `Inventory` item going to be listed under more than one `Plant`? If so, you need a many-to-many relationship, otherwise a one-to-many one. Is it possible that an `Inventory` item is not listed in any plant? Make the relationship optional. It's as simple as that

Comment: @crizzis Thanks again. I think I am supposed to use many-to-many relationship based on your comment. One plant can have multiple Inventories and similarly another plant can hold the same set of inventories? Should I use many-to-many? If yes, please share what I have to consider

When I say reference table, all the inventories are stored in inventory table and allow the plants to map to different inventories?

Comment: @crizzis Infact I started with Many-to-many but the inventory was not holding the modified values rather it was fetching from the reference/base table.. If you can guide me with what exactly the mapping I should use and any reference will be helpful

Comment: Do you mean there are values you want to modify in an `Inventory`, but only for a specific `Plant`? In that case, there is no other way but to introduce an intermediary entity between `Plant` and `Inventory`. You will then have two one-to-many relationships instead of a single many-to-many one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136632/discussion-between-crazymac-and-crizzis).

Answer (score 2):

This answers the **UPDATE 2** part:

As I understand, `Plant` and `Inventory` are in a many-to-many relationship, but there are additional properties that are to be stored along with the information that a specific `Plant` is holding a specific `Inventory` item.

In that case, you need an additional entity (let's call it `StockItem`) that will be used to hold that additional state. Both `Plant` and `Inventory` will then be in a one-to-many relationship with the new entity.

Your mapping will then become:

```
class Plant {
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "plant_id")
    private Set<StockItem> stockItems;
    ...
}

class StockItem {
    @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "stockItems")
    private Plant plant;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinColumn(name = "inventory_id")
    private Inventory inventory;

    //put any fields here that may vary from one plant to plant to another
    private int quantity;

}

class Inventory {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "inventory")
    public Set<StockItem> stockItems;

    // leave any fields that will NOT vary from one plant to another here
    private String name;
}
```

Things to note:

- This mapping assumes that you will be adding new `StockItem`s to a `Plant` (new items added to `Inventory.stockItems` will be ignored by JPA), in which case it will be enough to set the `StockItem.inventory` field to a proper value, add the `StockItem` to the `Plant.stockItems` list, and save the `Plant` entity
- The `StockItem.plant` and `Inventory.stockItems` are not absolutely necessary, remove them if you do not need them

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response I will try this and let you know

Comment: I was not able to resolve with the above code but it guided me to  resolve the problem. So I am not marking it as answer but voted one. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that those Inventory entities are detached and the Persistence Provider is not considering them during flush. You do not get an exception as @OneToMany is a special kind of relationship in flush algorithm because the act of persisting the owning entity does not depend on the target thus Hibernate will proceed and persist only the Plant entity.

Try using merge instead of persist:

```
plant.setListInventory(listInventory);
return plantRepository.merge(plant);
```

**Update**

You can also merge each inventory one by one using save as Spring JPA implicitly checks whether entity should be saved or merged:

```
for (Inventory inventory : listMaterial) {
     Inventory mergedInventory = inventoryRepository.save(inventory);
     mergedInventory.setPlant(plant);
     listInventory.add(mergedInventory);
}

plant.setListInventory(listInventory);
return plantRepository.save(plant);
```

Comment: I don't see an option of merge as part of the repository. In the repository, I se save and save & flush. Should I mention the merge as cascade type in the parent element?

Comment: cascade on plant side should be enough.. you can try to implement and expose merge by yourself.. entityManager.merge(enttiy).. or try out my updated solution.

Comment: I tried your updated solution and it goes infinite and throws an exception.
for (Inventory inventory : listMaterial) {
  Inventory mergedInventory = inventoryRepository.save(inventory);
   mergedInventory.setPlant(plant);
  listInventory.add(mergedInventory);}